# Why doesn't this JavaScript code(embedded as an HTML attribute)work?

Tags: javascript, html, onclick, dom-events

Why doesn't this work?

```
<button onclick = "function(){alert('Hello');}">press me</button>
```

while this does:

```
<button onclick = "alert('Hello');">press me</button>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They both work. The first one defines a function, but doesn't *call* it. The second one actually calls `alert`.

If you're trying to define and call an anonymous function, try this:

```
<button onclick = "(function(){alert('Hello');})()">press me</button>
```

Comment: oh...okay. That explains it! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Because you're not calling the function--you're defining it.

I don't know why you *would*, but you could write this:

```
<button onclick="(function() { alert('Hello'); })()">press me</button>
```